# How do you create an ITRS/Geneos alert for MSSQL DB

Tags: sql-server, geneos, itrs

I'm new to ITRS Monitoring, and I am wondering if I could create a Geneos alert that can connect to a MSSQL DB and run a simple select to make sure connectivity is good. Is this possible with Geneos? Are there any plugins needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use sql toolkit plug-in. It supports Db2, Oracle, SQL Server, MySql and Sybase. It will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, this looks pretty straightforward!  Really appreciate the screenshot.